# Choice of data-exchange method (JSON or conventional technique)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am writing an application where user can create their desired web-interface from the tools provided. I am providing them with several options to create multiple draggables and droppables and I want to store them in database when they design their interface. Is JSON good choice for the data-exchange in this case or simple implementation of some PHP code and/or some server-side scripting will serve better?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. You need a data format (which JSON is an example of) **and** some client side processing **and** some server side processing (which could be done using PHP).

Comment: I was thinking if just saving the position of say, for example, draggable, and sending it via some php method is better or not compared to storing them firstly in JSON and transporting it. Since I am a newbie, sorry if I am missing some key concepts.

Comment: You can't send it via some PHP method. The data will be on the client which doesn't have access to PHP methods except abstractly via making an HTTP request containing the data in some kind of data structure.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to say with some HTTP request. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply send the data as form data.

```
$.post(url, { key : value }, successHandler);
```

and then use php to read the form values from the post data and submit to database.

```
$_POST["key"]
```

Your question is way too broad to provide much more of an answer than this.